# How to get the workflow item details from livelink using c#?

Tags: c#, api, webservice-client, opentext, livelink

I have document in livelink and the document having workflow. In that workflow we have attachments and some default attributes.

My requirement to retrieve the workflow work item data. I tried to use the `workflowservice` to access the details. But I need `ProcessID` and `SubProcessID`.

Can any one tell me how to read the `ProcessID` and `SubProcessID`?

How to get the workflow work item data?
I used this function:
`workflowservice.GetWorkItemdata(wc,processID,subprocessId,activityID)`

Comment: Which version of Livelink/OpenText are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `listWorkItems()` method provided by `WorkflowService` web service interface.

I'm adding here the Java version showing how to retrieve work item data since I'm not confident with C#, but the procedure is almost the same:

```
WorkItemResult result = wfSvc.listWorkItems(null);
List<WorkItem> items = result.getWorkItems();
for (WorkItem item : items){
    // Attached data
    List<ApplicationData> dataList =
    wfSvc.getWorkItemData(item.getProcessID(), item.getSubProcessID(), item.getID());
    for (ApplicationData data : dataList){
       if (data instanceof AttributeData){
          AttributeData aData = (AttributeData) data;
          AttributeGroupDefinition groupDef = aData.getAttributes();
          for (Attribute attr : groupDef.getAttributes()) {
              if (attr instanceof StringAttribute) {
                  StringAttribute sAttr = (StringAttribute) attr;
                  System.out.println("Attr: " + sAttr.getDisplayName()+ " (" + sAttr.getValues().get(0) + ")");
              }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

The main point here is that the `listWorkItems` method allows you to easily access each work item's `ProcessID`, `SubProcessID` and `ID` values.

Comment: Thank you abarisone .I used your code like Workflowservice.Getworkitems().But I am gettting null value.